# How to Stop ColdFusion Targets from Opening in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, web-applications, jquery-events

I can't figure this out, I have tried every snippet of Javascript I can find which supposedly blocks links form opening in mobile Safari, but none of them work in my coldfusion webapp in standalone mode. In web mode it all works fine.

Link

```
<a class="button" href="rptSectors_bar.cfm" target="mainwindow">
```

Code I've tried:

```
    <script>

    function init() {
    $("a").click(function(e) { $("#content").load(e.target.href);return false; });
    }

    $(document).ready(init);

    </script>
```

Second One:

```
<script>
if (window.navigator.standalone) {

$(document).on(
"click",
"a",
"button,"
function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var aurl = $(event.target).attr("href");
    if (aurl) {
        location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
    }
    else {
        location.href = this;
        alert(this);
    }
}
);
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're doing here, but if I'm correct, could you not just remove the attribute itself from the DOM?

```
$("a").removeAttr("target");
```

*Assumes you are using jQuery in your app.*

Obviously this would be based on some `if () {} else {}` logic you have in place.

Hope that helps. Let me know if I'm understanding you totally incorrectly!

Comment: Didn't help specifically, but was a good confirmation I was on the right path. I got a solution in the end. Thanks!